# Jquery UI DatePicker is conflict with Material Design DatePicker

Tags: jquery-ui, material-design

In my application, I am using both Jquery UI and Google material design. I want to load Google MaterialDesign DatePicker. But, they are both conflicting each other. Please help me!..

Comment: Material design thingy also depends on jQuery..?

Comment: By the looks of it, it is not even a jquery plugin. Can you show how you're initializing it..? If possible a [mcve]